# How to change what fields are displayed in the Feed View?

Tags: case, account, page-layout, feeditem

In the Feed View of Account, we see this for all the cases related to the Account:

[image: feed view]

How could we remove the fields 'Status' or e.g. 'Priority' from this mini view? I can't seem to find where to add or remove fields for the displayed Records within a Feed...

Comment: Set up -> Feed Tracking -> Case -> Uncheck Status, Priority -> Save

Comment: Hello, has anybody found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The case feed displays the fields that are assigned to the compact layout for the object each feed item is for. I.e. if you want to change the fields displayed when a task is created on a case, change the fields in the compact layout for the task object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! I do however not work with Salesforce anymore so cannot verify whether this works. If other people can confirm, then I can accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having this issue as well and in order to remove certain fields (Priority, Case Owner) what worked was going to **Setup** and select **Feed Tracking**.

And then, on the Case object Feed Tracking, unchecking these fields will remove them from the Feed track.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps:

1. Create a new pagelayout with Feed-Based Layout chechbox checked in desired object.
2. Once page layout is created edit it .
3. Then in page layout editor go to feed view .
4. customize it to your liking .
5. save it.
6. Assign page layout to users.

Comment: Well, as you can see, we already have a Feed Layout, but the question is how we can hide/show fields of records in the Feed... I don't have these options in the page layout editor, as far as I can see...